# How to insert all Picklist values as Active in already inserted picklist field through metadata api

Tags: salesforce, apex, sfdc-metadata-api

I have the following code...but When i am inserting multi values to picklist field through metadata api all values are inserted but as inactive value only last value is inserted as active and this last active value make the all prior values as inactive.Please help.

```
    MetadataService.CustomObject customObj;
        customObj = new MetadataService.CustomObject();
        MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService();    
    MetadataService.CustomField customField = new MetadataService.CustomField();
    customField.fullName = objectName +'.'+ fieldName;
    customField.label =  fieldLabel;
    customField.type_x = fieldType;

    //Create the valueSet for picklist type
    MetadataService.ValueSet picklistValueSet = new MetadataService.ValueSet();

    //For each ValueSet, we have either ValueSetValuesDefinition or ValueSettings and some other attributes
    MetadataService.ValueSetValuesDefinition valueDefinition = new MetadataService.ValueSetValuesDefinition();

    List<MetadataService.CustomValue> values = new List<MetadataService.CustomValue>();
    MetadataService.CustomValue customValue1 = new MetadataService.CustomValue();
        //Adding "Default" value as one picklist value in the newly created picklist
      customValue1.fullName = valFullName ; 
      customValue1.description = '';
      customValue1.isActive =TRUE;
      customValue1.default_x = FALSE;
      customValue1.label = valLabel;
      values.add(customValue1);

    //It will be list of CustomValue
    valueDefinition.value = values;
    valueDefinition.sorted = false;

    //set the valueSetDefinition
    picklistValueSet.valueSetDefinition = valueDefinition;

    //Set the valueSet for picklist type
    customField.valueSet = picklistValueSet;
```

Answer (score -1):

That is not possible, you have to take the manual step to activate the picklist values inserted